# Can 2 Linq Queries be run parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, tfs-workitem, plinq

I have 2 Linq Queries, 1st Linq Query returns 1148 records and 2nd returns 6667 records. They take 8 minutes in execution. Is there any way to make them faster while running parallel?

```
var productbacklogworkitem =
               (from w in workItemcollectionList where w.Type.Name == "Product Backlog Item" select new {
                   Id = w.Id,
                   Name = w.Title,
                   FID = (w.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? ((w.WorkItemLinks[0].LinkTypeEnd.Name.ToString() != "Child") ? w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0) : 0,
                   Type = w.Type.Name,
                   State =w.State,
                   priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                   Size = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Effort"].Value),
                   StoryPoints = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Story Points"].Value),
                   DoneStatus = w.Fields["Done Status"].Value.ToString(),
                   StoryOwner = w.Fields["Story Owner"].Value.ToString(),
                   Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                   StoryAuthor = w.Fields["Story Author"].Value.ToString(),
                   IterationPath = w.IterationPath
               }).ToList();
            var taskbugsworkitem =
             (from w in workItemcollectionList where (w.Type.Name == "Task" || w.Type.Name == "Bug") && (w.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0)   select new {
                 Id = w.Id,
                 Name = w.Title,
                 Type = w.Type.Name,
                 Storyid =  w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId,
                 status = w.State,
                 IterationPath = w.IterationPath,
                 Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                 priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                 effort = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["effort"].Value),
                 Completed = (w.Type.Name== "Task") ? Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Completed"].Value):0
             }) .ToList();
```

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach` search for this tune your code into the mentioned format. It would be useful for the question.

Comment: Why are you pulling ~7000 records from the database with a single query?

Comment: just by chance 7k records are there @xxbbcc

Comment: @AkhilJain do you _need_ to pull all data in one go? Even in parallel it will not suddenly speed up massively, besides as your data grows it will likely just slow down more and more. Seems this is a good place to implement some paging, so you load only X rows each time from the database.

Comment: i am export the list in excel not any grid. @RMH pls tell the parallel way.

Comment: @AkhilJain could you show what the `workItemcollectionList` is and the class of the items within? You can omit stuff, as long you got a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of it. The answer of Anupam Singh seems good, but maybe fails due to some missing context.

Comment: Is this SQL query or `workItemcollectionList` just collection of items already in memory?

Comment: workcollectionlist

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Task` to make also two queries parallel.

```
Task<ResultClass1> t1 = Task<ResultClass1>.Run(() =>
    {
        var productbacklogworkitem =
        (from w in workItemcollectionList
         where w.Type.Name == "Product Backlog Item"
         select new ResultClass1
        {
            Id = w.Id,
            Name = w.Title,
            FID = (w.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? ((w.WorkItemLinks[0].LinkTypeEnd.Name.ToString() != "Child") ? w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0) : 0,
            Type = w.Type.Name,
            State = w.State,
            priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
            Size = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Effort"].Value),
            StoryPoints = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Story Points"].Value),
            DoneStatus = w.Fields["Done Status"].Value.ToString(),
            StoryOwner = w.Fields["Story Owner"].Value.ToString(),
            Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
            StoryAuthor = w.Fields["Story Author"].Value.ToString(),
            IterationPath = w.IterationPath
        }).ToList();

        return ResultClass1;
    });

Task<ResultClass2> t2 = Task<ResultClass2>.Run(() =>
    {
        var taskbugsworkitem =
            (from w in workItemcollectionList
            where (w.Type.Name == "Task" || w.Type.Name == "Bug") && (w.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0)
             select new ResultClass2
            {
                Id = w.Id,
                Name = w.Title,
                Type = w.Type.Name,
                Storyid = w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId,
                status = w.State,
                IterationPath = w.IterationPath,
                Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                effort = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["effort"].Value),
                Completed = (w.Type.Name == "Task") ? Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Completed"].Value) : 0
            }).ToList();

        return taskbugsworkitem;
    });

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

// get results from these
t1.Result;
t2.Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try PLINQ, using AsParallel() on entity

```
var productbacklogworkitem =
               (from w in workItemcollectionList.AsParallel() where w.Type.Name == "Product Backlog Item" select new {
                   Id = w.Id,
                   Name = w.Title,
                   FID = (w.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0) ? ((w.WorkItemLinks[0].LinkTypeEnd.Name.ToString() != "Child") ? w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId : 0) : 0,
                   Type = w.Type.Name,
                   State =w.State,
                   priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                   Size = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Effort"].Value),
                   StoryPoints = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Story Points"].Value),
                   DoneStatus = w.Fields["Done Status"].Value.ToString(),
                   StoryOwner = w.Fields["Story Owner"].Value.ToString(),
                   Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                   StoryAuthor = w.Fields["Story Author"].Value.ToString(),
                   IterationPath = w.IterationPath
               }).ToList();
            var taskbugsworkitem =
             (from w in workItemcollectionList.AsParallel() where (w.Type.Name == "Task" || w.Type.Name == "Bug") && (w.WorkItemLinks.Count > 0)   select new {
                 Id = w.Id,
                 Name = w.Title,
                 Type = w.Type.Name,
                 Storyid =  w.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId,
                 status = w.State,
                 IterationPath = w.IterationPath,
                 Assignedto = w.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString(),
                 priorty = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Priority"].Value),
                 effort = Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["effort"].Value),
                 Completed = (w.Type.Name== "Task") ? Convert.ToInt32(w.Fields["Completed"].Value):0
             }) .ToList();
```

For more info see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq

Comment: getting Error Collection was Modified Enumeration operation may not execute

Comment: sorry, not sure about the issue. but you can refer the link to explore the same.